# Powershell Subtract 1 textbox value from another

Tags: powershell

I am trying to subtract 1 `Textbox` value from another and output that in the second `Textbox`

please see example of what I am trying to achieve.

this is `Textbox1`

[image]

This is `Textbox2`

[image]

the subtraction I am trying to do is

```
$button3_Click = {
$sum1 = $textbox1.Text
$sum3 = $textbox2.text
    if($radiobutton3.checked -eq $true){
    $equals = $sum3 - $sum1 
    $textbox2.Text = $equals
    }
}
```

the outcome I would like is `Textbox2` to change to the answer 151, is this possible?

Comment: Change `$sum3 - $sum1` to `+$sum3 - $sum1`

Comment: thank you for your comment unfortunately this had no effect

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Make sure you cast the text to `[int]` so you can calculate it instead of concatinating it. scoping can be a problem because you are in a script block. Try `$global:textbox2.text = ...`. Is this homework or a real question?

Comment: So what happens? There's no obvious problem with your code. Note that when you use the `-` operator, PowerShell _implicitly_ converts the operands to numbers: `'301' - '150'`. @T-Me, while an `[int]` cast is advisable for conceptual reason, it isn't strictly necessary. Good point about scoping issues in general , but they don't apply here. Best to always avoid _global_ variables, and if this code lives in a _script_, you'd need `$script:...`

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, but it turned out that `Button3`  wasn't working, once I put a new button in and tried Mathias solution it worked